# How to Update Image in PHP?

Tags: php, mysql

I have a php page that updating image to db(longblub) 
please Any one help me image not updating 
alt text updating fine but other three fields not updating
Is the above code is right???if not pleases suggest me where i'm wrong???
please check the code below

```
<?php
$hostname = "localhost";
$dbuser = "user_e";
$dbpassword = "pwd_e";
$databasename = "test";

$bd = mysql_connect($hostname, $dbuser, $dbpassword) or die("Wrong username or   password.");
mysql_select_db($databasename, $bd) or die("Can't connect to the database");

if ((($_FILES["userFile"]["type"] == "image/gif")
  || ($_FILES["userFile"]["type"] == "image/jpeg")
  || ($_FILES["userFile"]["type"] == "image/png")
  || ($_FILES["userFile"]["type"] == "image/pjpeg"))
  && ($_FILES["userFile"]["size"] < 200000)) {

  if ($_FILES["userFile"]["error"] > 0) {
    echo "Return Code: " . $_FILES["userFile"]["error"] . "<br>";
  }
} 
$type= $_FILES['userFile']['type'];
$userFile= $_FILES['userFile']['name'];
$checkbox = $_POST['checkbox']; 
$countCheck = count($_POST['checkbox']);

for($i=0;$i<$countCheck;$i++) {
  $upd_id  = $checkbox[$i];
  // Temporary file name stored on the server 
  $tmpName  = $_FILES['userFile']['tmp_name'];   
  $imgData = addslashes(file_get_contents($_FILES["userFile"]["tmp_name"]));

  // Read the file 
  $fp   = fopen($tmpName, 'r'); 
  $data = fread($fp, filesize($tmpName)); 
  $data = addslashes($data); 

  fclose($fp); 

  {

  $data = mysql_real_escape_string($data);
  $alt = htmlentities($_POST['altText']);
  echo "upd item ". $upd_id;
  $sql ="UPDATE dtwelcome SET  type='".$_FILES['userFile']  ['type']."', name='.$userFile.',alt='.$alt.',img='.$imgData.' WHERE id= '$upd_id'";
  $result = mysql_query($sql,$bd);  
}

if($result) { 
  echo "success";
  //header('Location: ../../welcome.php');
}
else {
  echo "Error: ".mysql_error();
}
}

?>
```

Thanks

Comment: $sql ="UPDATE dtwelcome SET  type='".$_FILES['userFile']['type']."', name='"..$userFile."',alt='".$alt."',img='".$imgData."' WHERE id= '".$upd_id."'";

Comment: What's the value of `$_POST['altText']`?

Comment: Please to to keep a clean coding style.

Comment: please to check `Open brace` and `Close brace`.

Comment: I would not rely only on `$_FILES[...]['type']`. It may lead to security issue.

Answer (score 1):

Change your update statement to this code below.

```
$sql ="UPDATE dtwelcome SET  type='{$_FILES['userFile']['type']}', name='{$userFile}',alt='{$alt}',img='{$imgData}' WHERE id= '{$upd_id}'";
```

I think your concatenation sql string was wrong.

Avoid to save images on DB, instead of, prefer to save imagens on disk using move_uploaded_file and in database, save only the path you used to store the image on disk.

Comment: Hi Thanks
sql string working fine. but the problem is image not storing in database.